# WCF and streaming files

Tags: c#, wcf, filestreams

I have a WCF service that streams files with the following method:

```
public class GetFileService : IGetFileService
{
    public GetFileResponse GetFile(GetFileRequest request)
    {
        var fileStream = new FileStream(request.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        return new GetFileResponse
        {
            StreamResult = fileStream
        };
    }
}

[MessageContract]
public class GetFileResponse
{
    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
    public Stream StreamResult { get; set; }
}
```

My web.config has a basicHttpBinding with transferMode="Streamed" and so does the client that calls the service function

When the transfermode is set to streamed, it means that the service does not buffer the entire file in memory before it sends it, right? But what about the received (the client that calls the function).
If I have code that looks like the following on the receiver side:

```
GetFileServiceClient getFileService = new GetFileServiceClient();
using ( Stream stream = getFileService.GetFile(@"c:\Temp\pics.zip") )
{
    const int bufferSize = 2048;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    using (FileStream outputStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Temp\pics2.zip", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        int bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        while (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }
        outputStream.Close();
     }
 }
```

does the client not receive the whole file in the call to

```
 getFileService.GetFile(@"c:\Temp\pics.zip")
```

or does receive a stream pointer and the file is streamed only when calls to Read are performed in the while loop? Somehow I find that difficult to digest. I have the feeling that the whole file is sent through the network, and is lies somewhere in the WCF communication layer. If that is true, how do I go about using the stream in the client side in the correct way so that the client's memory is not occupied by what could be extremely large files.

Thanks

Comment: I'd always test a streaming solution because they are brittle. Stream a 100 GB file and you'll find out!

Comment: There's a nice little explanation here: https://nirajrules.wordpress.com/2009/08/03/mtom-vs-streaming-vs-compression-%E2%80%93-large-attachments-over-wcf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the transfermode is set to streamed, it means that the service
>   does not buffer the entire file in memory before it sends it, right?

Correct

> But what about the received (the client that calls the function). If
>   I have code that looks like the following on the receiver side does
>   the client not receive the whole file in the call to
>
> getFileService.GetFile(@"c:\Temp\pics.zip")

At some level, your network infrastructure is doing some amount of packet buffering, but there's nothing that buffers the entire stream before giving it to the client (or on the client side). The transport is managing the communication, and can be somewhat controlled in the binding using the maxBufferSize, maxBufferPoolSize, and maxReceivedMessageSize properties

Comment: So that means that the communication line is open until the last byte is read, or until the stream is closed?

Comment: @JihadHaddad For your purposes yes.  The truth is a little uglier as WCF can cache the connection and hold it open.  You can also look at turning on MTOM which is a widely supported standard.  It has some additional benefits, but for Java clients to stream from WCF this has to be turned on for large file transfer, otherwise java clients try and buffer the entire file in memory like you describe.   If you have just .NET clients, it takes care of it for you.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the answer. I actually tested your previous answer by inheriting from FileStream and overriding the Read() method. Using this class instead of FileStream, I saw calls to the overriden Read method on the service (by breaking into overriden code), while there were calls on the client to Read. This proves your statements correct. Thanks again